# Decoding RF receiver signals

Tags: arduino-nano

By using the following draft i decode the signals from an RF receiver

```
#define CH1 2
#define CH2 3
#define CH3 4
#define CH4 5
#define CH5 6
#define CH6 7

int ch1Time, ch2Time, ch3Time, ch4Time, ch5Time, ch6Time = 0;
void channels()
{
  TCNT1 = 0;
  ch1Time = 0; ch2Time = 0; ch3Time = 0; ch4Time = 0; ch5Time = 0; ch6Time = 0;

  while ((PIND & ((1 << CH1) | (1 << CH2) | (1 << CH3) | (1 << CH4) | (1 << CH5) | (1 << CH6))))
  {
    if (PIND & (1 << CH1))
      ch1Time = TCNT1;

    if (PIND & (1 << CH2))
      ch2Time = TCNT1;

    if (PIND & (1 << CH3))
      ch3Time = TCNT1;

    if (PIND & (1 << CH4))
      ch4Time = TCNT1;

    if (PIND & (1 << CH5))
      ch5Time = TCNT1;

    if (PIND & (1 << CH6))
      ch6Time = TCNT1;
  }
}
```

The issue is that i need also to use the 6 PWM's of the nano board.
So i thought of moving the channels 1-6 to the analog pins like so..

```
#define CH1 A0
#define CH2 A1
#define CH3 A2
#define CH4 A3
#define CH5 A4
#define CH6 A5


while ((PINC & ((1 << CH1) | (1 << CH2) | (1 << CH3) | (1 << CH4) | (1 << CH5) | (1 << CH6))))
  {
    if (PINC & (1 << CH1))
      ch1Time = TCNT1;
etc...
```

but it simply does not work. Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two immediate problems:

1. The macros A0-A5 are the numbers 14 to 19, not the numbers 0 to 5 - so you're looking at (1 << 14) for CH1 not (1 << 0).
2. The analog pins are port C not port B, so you need to use `PINC` not `PINB`.
3. Your `ch?Time` variables should be `volatile`.

Comment: Oups. I am actually using PORTC and that is a typo. I will edit it asap. The channels method is called by... attachInterrupt(0, channels, RISING);

Comment: Actually i do not get it. (PINC & (1 << 0)) for CH1 does not work also, with pinMode(A0, INPUT);

Comment: Added the volatile option but the issue remains.

Comment: @OrElse Are you sure you want to be clearing TCNT1 just before you read from it?

Comment: Actually yes. This way by counting the time, i decode the RF receiver signal which is from 1ms to 2ms. Plus this works great on digital inputs. TCCR1A = 0;
  TIMSK1 = 0;
  TIFR1 = 0;
  TCNT1 = 0;
  TCCR1B = (1 << CS10); Thank you for all your effort

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you're doing with it now.